# Django field isn't being migrated

Tags: python, django

I have a model, for each object I want a random string on creation `activation`.

I'm currently creating the model like so;

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
import string
import random

def get_random_12_string():
    return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=12))


class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='customer')

    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='clients')
    phone_number = models.CharField(_("Phone Number"), max_length=15)  
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(_("Date of Birth"), blank=True, null=True)  # Optional

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Created At"), auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Updated At"), auto_now=True)
    activation = models.CharField(_("Activation Code"), max_length=14, default=get_random_12_string)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Customer")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Customers")
        ordering = ['created_at']  # Orders by creation date by default in queries.
```

However after running `python manage.py makemigrations` & `python manage.py migrate` (both saying they are succesful). The field doesn't even get created in the database and when going to the admin panel I am getting an error that the field doesn't exist.

```
Migrations for 'portal':
  portal\migrations\0005_alter_client_activation.py
    - Alter field activation on client

Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, api, auth, contenttypes, cookie_consent, portal, public, sessions, sites
Running migrations:
  Applying portal.0005_alter_client_activation... OK
```

[image: MariaDB Table Schema]

Migration file(s).
001_initial.py

```
# Generated by Django 3.2.23 on 2024-03-26 04:18

import datetime
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
import portal.models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Client',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('phone_number', models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name='Phone Number')),
                ('date_of_birth', models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Date of Birth')),
                ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Created At')),
                ('updated_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Updated At')),
                ('activation', models.CharField(default=portal.models.get_random_12_string, max_length=14, verbose_name='Activation Code')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Customer',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'Customers',
                'ordering': ['created_at'],
            },
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='client',
            name='organization',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='clients', to='portal.organization'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='client',
            name='user',
            field=models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='customer', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Show the contents of `0005_alter_client_activation.py`

Comment: Show the output of `python manage.py showmigrations portal` (Here portal is your app name)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I deleted all the previous migrations and have a clean migration (0001_initial). Posted its contents.

Answer (score 0):

> However after running python manage.py makemigrations & python manage.py migrate (both saying they are succesful). The field doesn't even get created in the database and when going to the admin panel I am getting an error that the field doesn't exist.

append your app name after migration commands.

e.g

```bash
python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name
python manage.py migrate your_app_name
```

Comment: Tried this already and it did not work, the app is is `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: then you can  try deleting all migration files and run migrate commands again

Comment: Deleted all migration files, ran `makemigrations` (executed fine). Ran `migrate` and it said no migrations to apply.

Comment: @fiji why did you do that? Deleting the migration files without understanding what went wrong is a nuclear option and should be the last choice. Given you've done that you might as well delete / drop the database too to have a fresh start.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat 4 of the migration files were me just changing various things in the field to try and figure out what went wrong. This field was never created and still isn't being made by Django.